# Proto Serializing hierarchy type with Reflection

Tags: .net, serialization, reflection, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

when trying to serialize a hierarchy type with proto serializer that has been loaded by reflection it seems to have some weird behavior and does not really seem to work.

here is the code:

```
    [ProtoContract]
    [ProtoInclude(10, typeof(Derived))]
    class Base
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string BaseFirstProperty { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public string BaseSecProperty { get; set; }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    class Derived : Base
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string DerivedFirstProperty { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"c:\protobuf-net.dll");

        var derived = new Derived()
        {
            BaseFirstProperty = "BaseFirst",
            BaseSecProperty = "BaseSec",
            DerivedFirstProperty = "DerivedFirst"
        };

        var reflectionSerializer = assembly.GetType("ProtoBuf.Serializer");
        var getTypeSerializer = typeof(Serializer);

        var reflectionMethods = reflectionSerializer.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        var reflectionGenericMethodInfo = reflectionMethods.First<MethodInfo>(method => method.Name == "SerializeWithLengthPrefix");
        var reflectionSpecificMethodInfo = reflectionGenericMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { derived.GetType() });

        var getTypeMethods = getTypeSerializer.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        var getTypeGenericMethodInfo = getTypeMethods.First<MethodInfo>(method => method.Name == "SerializeWithLengthPrefix");
        var getTypeSpecificMethodInfo = getTypeGenericMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { derived.GetType() });

        var reflectionStream = new MemoryStream();
        var getTypeStream = new MemoryStream();
        reflectionSpecificMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { reflectionStream, derived, PrefixStyle.Base128 });
        getTypeSpecificMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { getTypeStream, derived, PrefixStyle.Base128 });

        Console.WriteLine(reflectionStream.ToArray().Length); // Prints out 15
        Console.WriteLine(getTypeStream.ToArray().Length); // Prints out 37
    }
```

As far as I know it should work the same so... What am I doing wrong?
Please note that I am using Proto-buf 2.0.0.431.
Thanks,

Comment: have seen the question; will look, but have day-job to do too

Answer (score 0):

incorrect ordering

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(10, typeof(Derived))]
class Base
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string BaseFirstProperty { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string BaseSecProperty { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
class Derived : Base
{
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public string DerivedFirstProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok; I've run it through the current trunk code; I initially got an error processing `ImplicitFields`, but I have corrected that locally. Then running it, I get:

```
37
37
```

which suggests to me that it the issue is already fixed in one if the last (625-431)=194 commits. Don't ask me which one! I would recommend that you try r625 and see how that goes, I haven't deployed that yet, but the protobuf-net project should build, or let me know if you want me to email it to you.

Also: you may find it easier to use the non-generic API, rather than `MakeGenericMethod`; that is either `ProtoBuf.Serializer.NonGeneric`, or `ProtoBuf.RuntimeTypeModel.Default` (basically, the *generic* `Serializer` API now just forwards to the *non-generic* API, since the v2 core ripped out all of the generic code; there is absolutely no advantage is using the generic API, other than convenience - which you don't have when using reflection).

Comment: Hi Matc, I have tried it with the 622 and also got the ImplicitFields error. What do you mean by "corrected it locally?". and please do send the r625 to me.

Comment: @Moti yes, < 625 the ImplicitFields glitch will bite; by "corrected it locally" I mean I've changed the code on my dev box to make it work. I'm not at PC now, but will send later

Comment: it works like a charm.. So I will just have to wait for the next stable version. Thank you!

Comment: @Moti there's a couple of things (completely unrelated to this) that I want to tidy up before I deploy a public build - hopefully at the weekend

Comment: Great! earlier than I thought! Thank you!